Нужна ли запятая перед вторым тире?
Мудрость директора - в правильности принимаемых им решений, - такого мнения придерживается мой коллега.

✦ Я думаю, что запятая нужна.
Мудрость директора — в правильности принимаемых им решений, — такого мнения придерживается мой коллега.

2. Запятая и тире ставятся между двумя частями бессоюзного сложного предложения, из которых вторая носит присоединительный характер с каким-либо дополнительным оттенком значения (пояснительным, временным, условно-следственным и др.); нередко эта часть начинается местоименными словами тот, так, такой и т. п.: <...> Все предметы вокруг были отчётливы и преувеличенно реальны, — так бывает, когда не спишь всю ночь (Ш.); Она сидела неподалёку на скамье под покосившимся деревянным грибом, — такие делают в лагерях для часовых (Пауст.).

Другой момент: если не поставить запятую, то возникает ощущение, что конструкция, обрамленная тире, является вставкой. Это мешает сразу осознать смысл предложения. Запятая же помогает понять, где заканчивается первая часть предложения.
✦ Есть, мне кажется, и другой вариант пунктуационного решения.
Если слова коллеги приводятся дословно (то есть они действительно были сказаны), то тут уже необходимо оформление с прямой речью: с кавычками, но без запятой.
«Мудрость директора — в правильности принимаемых им решений» — такого мнения придерживается мой коллега.

Примечания: 1. После закрывающих кавычек ставится только тире (независимо от того, каким знаком препинания заканчивается прямая речь) в тех случаях, когда в последующих словах автора содержится характеристика прямой речи, ее оценка и т. д. (авторская ремарка обычно начинается словами: так говорит, так указывает, вот что сказал, вот как описывает и т. п.): <...> «Нет ничего прекраснее этих снежных вершин» — так описывает эту местность один путешественник; «Будь внимателен и осторожен!» — вот что он сказал мне на прощание.

Запятая и тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении
Прямая речь перед словами автора
P. S. Вместо дефиса, конечно же, в предложении нужно писать тире (Alt + 0151).

А какую роль выполняет здесь двойное тире?

М-м... Здесь нет двойного (парного) тире, Серж. (День добрый! Давненько не общались.) Первое — на месте пропуска сказуемого; второе — знак в БСП. (Ух ты, уже ж вечер!)

Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ! Не поняла только про Alt + 0151. Как это? У меня не работает (

Вот: https://webstyle.sfu-kras.ru/tire-defis. Держим Alt и набираем подряд (справа) 0151, отпускаем Alt. Тире должно изобразиться. Ещё (на будущее):  Alt + 0171 = «;  Alt + 0187 = ». Очень удобно.

Отказываться от первого тире совсем не хочется, так как начало предложения будет плохо восприниматься. Тут делается акцент на одном из первых слов (в зависимости от контекста), после чего появляется пауза, обозначенная этим тире.
А чтобы не было ощущения вставки и не возникали сомнения насчёт пунктуации, предлагаю варианты попроще:
Мудрость директора — в правильности принимаемых им решений. Такого мнения придерживается мой коллега.
Да, связь между предложениями немного теряется, но это некритично.
Мудрость директора — в правильности принимаемых им решений (такого мнения придерживается мой коллега).

Это дело вкуса. Какие-то изменения должны быть. Можно добавить глагол состоит/заключается или разбить предложение на части.  Можно скобки. Но без контекста это будет угадывание возможных вариантов, а что лучше подходит – неясно.  Но только не два тире.

В качестве варианта:
Мудрость директора (состоит) в правильности принимаемых им решений — такого мнения придерживается мой коллега.
Пояснение

Два тире в этом предложении нежелательны:  даже при наличии запятой кажется, что это вставка.  Я сначала прочитала именно так. А иначе придется всем объяснять, какую роль играет здесь двойное тире. Другими словами, знаки препинания не определяют грамматику предложения ОДНОЗНАЧНО.

Задача решается по правилу  Розенталя § 45. Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении
8. Тире ставится перед местоименными словами так, такой, 
таков, начинающими собой присоединительное предложение, 
входящее в состав бессоюзного сложного предложения: 
Приказ  есть приказ — так его воспитал фронт (Вор.); 
Кривые улицы, маленькие деревянные дома — такой была 
значительная часть  Москвы в начале XX века. Идти вперёд 
или погибнуть — таков был выбор у партизанского отряда; 



Обратим внимание:
В этих предложениях выражены суждения, субъект которых 
назван в первой части, а предикат образует вторую часть. 
Если логические отношения между обеими частями носят другой 
характер, то между ними ставятся запятая и тире: Загрязнение 
окружающей среды угрожает жизни на Земле, — так дальше 
продолжаться не может (Газ.).

Я полагаю, что в заданном предложении выражено именно суждение.  Сравнить: Мудрость директора  в правильности принимаемых им решений — это мнение моего коллеги (субъект и предикат, подлежащее и сказуемое).
Единый знак (запятая и тире) обозначает значительно увеличенную паузу, которая здесь нежелательна (имеет место более тесная связь предложений).
